# Hint for Fourier series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Hi there I have a a question $f(x)=\begin{cases} 2x^2-x^4 & x \in [-1,1) \\  f(x+2)& \forall x \end{cases}
$

How would I go about finding the Fourier series for $f(x)$  I'm confused by the second part because it has an $f(x+2)$ in it

Comment: MathJax hint:  to show a function by cases, use \begin {cases} at the start and \end {cases} at the end.  You can right click and show Math as -> Tex commands to see how I did it.  Also to get "element of" you can use \in to get $\in$

Answer (score 1):

The point is that $f(x)$ is periodic with period $2$, which is what the second line says.  To do the Fourier expansion, just concentrate on $[-1,1)$ and the expression in the first line.

Comment: oh right so I just have to focus on the first line 2x^2-x^4 and just use period 2?